# Python Can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple error

Tags: python

I have a function in python that gets ips from the database, I want to iterate over them and call ping function but i get an error "Can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple error" in the subject area. When i say print where the function show(ipps) has been called, it only prints the last value in the array

json dumps return

```
{"ip addresses": [["192.168.0.11"], ["192.168.0.12"], ["192.168.0.13"], ["192.168.0.15"]]}

@ps_gaming.route('/getPSStatusping')
def getPSStatusping():
    try:
        if session.get('id'):
            con = mysql.connect()
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_getPSIPSstats')
            all_my_ps = cursor.fetchall()

            for ipps in all_my_ps:
                show(ipps) //error is thrown here
            return json.dumps({"ip_addresses":all_my_ps})
        else:
            return render_template('error.html', error='Unauthorized Access')
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html', error=str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
```

other functions

```
def isUp(hostname):
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    print(output)

    if ('unreachable' in output):
        return '0'
    else:
        return '1'

def show(hostname1):    
    value = isUp(hostname1)

    if ('1' in value):
        print hostname1 + ' Is Active'
    else:
        print hostname1 + ' Is Unreachable'
```

Any Suggestions

Comment: what line is the error thrown on?

Comment: The line where there is  "show(ipps)"

Comment: Is there any particular reason your JSON has a list of nested lists containing only 1 element? Isn't this better? `{"ip addresses": ["192.168.0.11", "192.168.0.12", "192.168.0.13", "192.168.0.15"]}`

Comment: The JSON does that when i call cursor.fetchall(), how can i stop it from nesting?

Comment: @cricket_007: I think the json has nested tuples is because it comes from a database query. It is a tuple of rows, with each row being a tuple of columns. There's only one column, but it's still represented as a list within json.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley, that explains it all

Comment: @BryanOakley - I figured as much, but a little processing  into unnested lists would save some headache later. For example, the current error could be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Within `show`, `hostname1` is a tuple. You try to add a string to it, hence the error that you see. You need to either convert `hostname1` to a string, or extract a string value out of it. My guess is, the `hostname1` tuple only contains a single value, so you can use something like `print hostname1[0] + ' Is Active'`

`hostname1` is a tuple because `cursor.fetchall()` will return a tuple (rows) of tuples(columns), and you iterate over the outer tuple. Within each iteration, `ipps` itself is a tuple (though, possibly with only a single element within that tuple). Even though each row apparently contains only a single column the query still returns each row as a tuple. When you convert it to json, it is represented as a nested list.

Comment: Nit-pick: I'm pretty sure that `.fetchall()` returns a *list* of tuples, not a *tuple* of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

In your `show` function, try casting `hostname1` to a string, i.e. do `print str(hostname1) + ' is active'`, and likewise for unreachable